# C file accessing CPP class by reference hits fatal error (InstrFetchProhibited)

Tags: c++, c, exception, scope, esp32

I'm working on an ESP32 program that gets BLE data in C code and parses it using C++ classes. I originally had a friend helping with the C++ part, but since he doesn't have free time for this any more I'm trying to improve my C++ skills by working with those classes and adding some of my own, but it has made this project more difficult for me to separate syntax issues from my usual dumb mistakes.

Originally, this project started with an ESP32 example written in C for a GATT server that I modified to do what I needed. Then, I created a wrapper so the GATT server could send data to the CPP parser my friend made (this wrapper was more or less from similar Stack Overflow questions on C/C++ functions)

```
//C interface wrapper functions
extern "C" void* parser_create(void* TxFunc) {
   return new parser((serialTx) TxFunc);
}
extern "C" void parser_release(void* parserInstance) {
   delete static_cast<Parser*>(parserInstance);
}
extern "C" void parser_Rx(void* parserInstance, const uint8_t *rxData, size_t rxLen) {
   static_cast<parser*>(parserInstance)->serialRx(rxData, rxLen);
}
```

When the class was created using parser_create() in the C file, this worked great. However, other classes also need access to the parser class so they can add data, and it didn't seem to make sense for that to "live" in the BLE's C code. I tried to change the C code to simply take a pointer to the parser class after it's instantiated in main, but otherwise use it the same, and this is where I've run into issues.

```
//In Parser's header file
class Parser {
    public:
        Parser(serialTx txCallback);        
        void serialRx(const uint8_t *rxData, size_t rxLen);
        
        serialTx txCallback;
        ...
};

//In BLE C file
void* parserClass;
...   
-void ble_init()
+void ble_init(void* parserClassPtr)
 {
-   parserClass = parser_create(TxFunc);
+   parserClass = parserClassPtr;
 }

//in main.cpp, where I'm hoping to instantiate the different classes and show the interaction more clearly

//This transmit function is passed into the parser class to tell it how to send data. The exception is thrown before this function is used, so it's mostly here for clarity
void transmitFunction(const uint8_t *txData, size_t txLen)
{...

}
 extern "C" void app_main()
{
...
-    ble_init();
+    Parser parserInstance(transmitFunction);
+    ble_init(&parserInstance);
 }
```

Now the code runs, but when the BLE code gets data and tries to call "parser_Rx", I get an unhandled exception for InstrFetchProhibited.

First I tried increasing stack size to make sure this wasn't a stack issue. Then, I tried printing the address of the class after instantiation and before the Rx function call to verify the pointer wasn't corrupted. The problem ultimately seems to be with the C code calling the parser's receive function now that the class is in main. Why would this be? Other than a "scope issue" I'm struggling with what to even search for.

Comment: You seem to set the `TxFunc` but not the `RxFunc`? Can you please try to create a [mre] to show us?

Comment: Thanks, @Someprogrammerdude - TxFunc gets called in to show the class how to transmit responses, while RxFunc is a public member of the parser's class. I added those details of the class to make what's going on more clear. 

In practice, the exception occurs before the parser handles any data, so it's something to do with the call to the class' RxFunc.

So far I'm debating just writing the BLE code in CPP or creating another task to move data to and from BLE with queues (currently how the TX callback works).. but this seems like a simple issue I would like to understand

Comment: `void ble_init(void* parserClassPtr)` Passes the pointer by value, making a copy of the pointer. Whatever a pointer points at is passed by reference, but the pointer itself... That's still being passed by value, so when `parserClass = parserClassPtr;` runs the copy that is `parserClass` is changed. The pointer provided as an argument to `ble_init`, and was copied, is unchanged. Pass in a pointer to a pointer so you can modify the argument in the function. That said, I'd prefer for `ble_init` to return the pointer. `void* ble_init() {
return parser_create(TxFunc); }`